# oidc-client-js always redirect to login page

Tags: javascript, openid-connect

I am working on a project to set up OIDC authentication on a react SPA (authorization code with PKCE).
I am working with the oidc-client-js library.
My code works fine but after being authenticated I am again redirected to the login pattern.
I looked at the react router side but that doesn't seem to be it. I am thinking of an asynchronous problem but I can't seem to get out of it. Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

My configuration

```
const userManager = new UserManager({
authority: identityProvider,
client_id: window.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
response_type: 'code',
redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/auth-callback',
scope: 'openid',
loadUserInfo: false,
revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
filterProtocolClaims: true,
monitorSession: true,
metadata: {
    issuer: identityProvider,
    jwks_uri: `${identityProvider}/pf/JWKS`,
    end_session_endpoint: `${identityProvider}/idp/startSLO.ping`,
    authorization_endpoint: `${identityProvider}/as/authorization.oauth2`,
    token_endpoint: `${identityProvider}/as/token.oauth2`,
    userinfo_endpoint: `${identityProvider}/idp/userinfo.openid`,
    revocation_endpoint: `${identityProvider}/as/revoke_token.oauth2`,
    introspection_endpoint: `${identityProvider}/as/introspect.oauth2`
}
```

})

My AuthProvider

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import IdentityProvider from './bo-authentication/context/IdentityProvider'
import useCompleteAuthentication from './useCompleteAuthentication'
import useStartAuthentication from './useStartAuthentication'

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)

useStartAuthentication()
const boAuthentication = useCompleteAuthentication()
console.log(boAuthentication)

useEffect(() => {
    setReady(boAuthentication.token !== undefined)
}, [boAuthentication.token])

if (!ready) return null

return <IdentityProvider value={boAuthentication}>{children}</IdentityProvider>
}

AuthProvider.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.node }

export default AuthProvider
```

My Service

```
export const login = async () => {
await userManager
    .signinRedirect({ redirectUri: window.location.href })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`User login successful`)
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(`An error occur during user login flow ${error}`))
}

export const completeAuthentication = once(
async (updater: UserAuthenticationUpdater = () => undefined): Promise<void> => {
    await userManager
        .signinRedirectCallback()
        .then((user: User | null) => {
            if (!user?.access_token) {
                console.warn('The identity provider have not provide the access token')
            } else {
                const userAuthentication = getUserAuthentication(user)
                updater(userAuthentication)
                const millisecondsBeforeExpiration = getMillisecondsBeforeExpiration(
                    userAuthentication.exp as number
                )
                console.log(`The time before refresh token is ${millisecondsBeforeExpiration}`)
            }
        })
        .catch(() => console.error('An error occur during the handle callback from the identity provider'))
}
```

)

Hooks

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { completeAuthentication } from '..'
import AuthenticationContext from '../context/AuthenticationContext'
import { UserAuthentication } from '../model/userAuthentication'

const useBoAuthentication = (): UserAuthentication => {
const authenticationContextValue = useContext(AuthenticationContext)

const [authenticationContext, setAuthenticationContext] = useState<UserAuthentication>(authenticationContextValue)

useEffect(() => {
    if (authenticationContextValue.authenticated) return
    completeAuthentication(setAuthenticationContext)
}, [authenticationContextValue.authenticated])

return authenticationContext
```

}

export default useBoAuthentication

Hooks

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import AuthenticationContext from '../context/AuthenticationContext'
import { login } from '../index'

const useStartAuthentication = () => {
const authenticationContextValue = useContext(AuthenticationContext)

useEffect(() => {
    if (authenticationContextValue.authenticated) return
    login()
}, [authenticationContextValue.authenticated])
}

export default useStartAuthentication
```

Comment: I'am sorry, 'Hello' is not displayed on my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put tighter control over when signInRedirect is called, based on whether userManager.getUser returns anything. I would start with this approach:

- When the page loads, render the logged in state to a label on screen: true or false
- Use a temporary login button to trigger sign in redirects rather than doing it automatically in useEffect

Once that is reliable you can put back the onLoad automatic redirect. If it helps, here is [some code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts) to compare against - you can run this code sample very easily also.

Comment: Hello Gary,

Thanks, I will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

It works when I check the user in the userManager instance. I thought my verification on authenticated at the hooks level was sufficient.

Thank you very much for your efficiency and reactivity.